# webgl how to draw many cubes

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to draw 5161 cubes using webGL. The problem is not all cubes are drawn. Upon some searching, I think its because I am passing too many vertices in one VBO call. You can take a look at jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5fjhe21/. You can move around with QWERASDF and arrows keys but it isnt well implemented right now.

My draw call used to look like this:

```
function render(){
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_matrixLoc, false, new Float32Array(pMatrix));
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, data.triangles.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

So I would do is data.pushData() once and render as needed; It was fast. glObject is an array of Cubes.

```
data.pushData = function(){
// pushData once then call drawElements on every render call doesnt work as I hit some kind of limit;
// not all cubes are drawn; I think the draw calls must be split up;
data.vertices = [];
data.uv = [];
data.triangles = [];
var vertexOffset = 0;

glObjects.forEach(function pushingObject(o){
    data.vertices.push.apply(data.vertices,o.vertices);
    data.uv.push.apply(data.uv,o.uv);
    o.triangles.forEach(function pushingTriangles(index){
        data.triangles.push(index+vertexOffset);
    });

    vertexOffset += o.vertices.length/3; // change to component length later
});

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data.vertices),gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW );
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data.uv),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(data.triangles), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW );
};
```

But the problem (I think) is that I am passing in too many vertices at once. So I tried to merge pushData and render together:

```
data.render = function(){
    data.vertices = [];
    data.uv = [];
    data.triangles = [];
    var vertexOffset = 0;

    glObjects.forEach(function pushingObject(o){
        if (vertexOffset + o.vertices.length > 65536){
            vertexOffset = 0;
            glDraw();
            data.vertices.length = 0;
            data.uv.length = 0;
            data.triangles.length = 0;
        }

        data.vertices.push.apply(data.vertices,o.vertices);
        data.uv.push.apply(data.uv,o.uv);
        o.triangles.forEach(function pushingTriangles(index){
            data.triangles.push(index+vertexOffset);
        });

        vertexOffset += o.vertices.length/3; // change to component length later
    });

    glDraw();

    function glDraw(){
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data.vertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data.uv),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(data.triangles), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, data.triangles.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
};
```

But this isnt fast enough because as I learnt, passing in new bufferData is slow. So my question is, what does one do in this situation? I was unable to locate any webgl resource that deal with this. My feeling leans towards creating multiple VBO objects but I want to make sure I am going in the right direction first. And as a follow up question, suppose if one need to draw many cubes all with unique position (x,y,z) and orientation (rX,rY,rZ), how does one go about implementing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved my problem and I'll leave this here for stragglers:

Basically, I had the right idea in that I need to use multiple draw calls as each indexed draw (drawElements) can only refer to 2^16 elements in a VBO. The flaw in my first implementation is that I actually tried to reconstruct a new big typedArray made of multiple cube vertices in every render call. Needless to say, that is very slow. So instead of that, I really should have only created the typedArray/buffer once. To overcome the 2^16 element reference limitation, all I have to do is to separate the one bigass typedArray into manageable sizes, and this is exactly what this new version of pushData does:

```
data.pushData = function(){
    // ensure each vertex attribute has less than 2^16 vertices because that is how many that be be referenced each time
    // with gl.drawElements call

    function newChunk(){
        return {
            vertices: [],
            uv: [],
            triangles: []
        }
    }
    var chunk = newChunk();

    var vertexOffset = 0;

    glObjects.forEach(function pushingVerts(o){
        if (vertexOffset + o.vertices.length > 65536){
            vertexOffset = 0;
            data.chunks.push(chunk);
            chunk = newChunk();
        }

        chunk.vertices.push.apply(chunk.vertices,o.vertices);
        chunk.uv.push.apply(chunk.uv,o.uv);
        o.triangles.forEach(function pushingTriangles(index){
            chunk.triangles.push(index+vertexOffset);
        });

        vertexOffset += o.vertices.length/3; // change to component length later
    });

    data.chunks.push(chunk);

    data.chunks.forEach(function toTypeArray(c){
        c.vertices = new Float32Array(c.vertices);
        c.uv = new Float32Array(c.uv);
        c.triangles = new Uint16Array(c.triangles);
    });

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeofFloat * 65536*3,gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeofFloat * 65536*2,gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeofFloat * 65536, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // for some reason only allocating sizeofUnsignedShort * 65536 is not enough.

    return data.chunks;
};
```

Then for render its simply:

```
data.renderChunks = function(){

    data.chunks.forEach(function renderChunk(c){
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,  0, c.vertices);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
        gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,  0, c.uv);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
        gl.bufferSubData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, c.triangles);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, c.triangles.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    });
};
```

Also I changed from using gl.bufferData to gl.bufferSubData to avoid the overhead of constructing a new buffer.

And with this I can now draw 60,000 cubes (at least):
http://jsfiddle.net/n5fjhe21/1/